# If a field is blank in Excel then generate 'NL-1, NL-2........Nl-n' automatically on a button click

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to build a button in excel such that on clicking it, it generates 'NL-1, NL-2, ..... NL-n' until the end of the row in Excel.

For example

```
Sample No    Value       
123           1
245           2
              3
345           4
678           5
345           6
              7
              8
347           9
678          10
343          11
             12
098          13
```

On clicking the button

```
Sample No    Value       
123           1
245           2
NL-1          3
345           4
678           5
345           6
NL-2          7
NL-3          8
347           9
678          10
343          11
NL-4         12
098          13
```

I was able to built a logic using a third reference column and an IF statement 
i.e. IF(A$2="",C$2) where C was "NL-1......NL-99"  and it gave me a solution like this

```
Sample No    Value     NL(Hidden)  
123           1          NL-1
245           2          NL-2
NL-3          3          NL-3
345           4          NL-4
678           5          NL-5
345           6          NL-6
NL-7          7          NL-7
NL-8          8          NL-8
```

But I would like to have it as the second table as shown!
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Should be relatively easy if you can use a helper column. In column C, you could put `=IF(A2="","NL-"&COUNTIF($A$1:A2,""),A2)` and drag down. That's the formula, now you just need to make the macro that adds to your range.

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne it worked perfectly!

Comment: Sorry @JvdV I tried using a IF function and updated the solution. I am just learning excel macros and also new to this forum and hence the incomplete question! Thanks for pointing that out, I will remember to put my code next time.

Comment: That's fine, I guess you are not using any code at all then? Just worksheet formulas?

Comment: @BruceWayne I cannot find a way to give your comment an upvote, please let me know if there is something I can do to rate your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JvdV I want to build a button to do this, I was just trying to figure out the logic of how I can do this. I don't know if my approach is correct. I am just trying to watch some videos on youtube and figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are obviously several ways to tackle this, let me show you one:

---

***Without VBA or helper column***

- Select your column A range `A2:A14`
- Press <kbd>F5</kbd> > `Special` > `Empty Values` > `OK`
- Press <kbd>F2</kbd> or place your cursor in the Formula Bar
- Enter the following formula: `="NL-"&COUNTIF($A$1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1),"NL-*")+1`
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

***With VBA***

Assign the following to your button:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, cl As Range

With Sheet1 'Change this into the CodeName of the sheet you refering too
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = .Range("A1:A" & lr)
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng1) > 0 Then
        Set rng2 = Intersect(rng1, rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))
        x = 1
        For Each cl In rng2
            cl.Value = "NL-" & x
            x = x + 1
        Next cl
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! This is perfect, my next step is to build the logic behind a button!

Comment: @RupeshGhosh, building this in VBA requires different steps to follow and would not really look like this at all. One thing it will have in common are A) a `Range` object and B) a iteration through empty cells.

Comment: Oh I see, I will try to figure it out. Also, if you could direct me to some materials where I can learn VBA coding, especially to a similar thing like this, then that would be great.Thank you.

Comment: @RupeshGhosh, I couldn't help myself but to quickly piece the edited answer together. Try to understand the logic in the macro instead of simply implementing it. Btw, the `CodeName` of your sheet is not the same as the name of the sheet. You'll find it in the VBE Project Explorer (google will guide you).

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it! Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you for the code, I will surely understand the macro first. I want to learn this as it is a necessary skill, truly appreciate your help.